# How to connect to the database in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to build a simple Magento Module that needs to connect to the database at the start of each page request. All tables need to be accessible to it. I've been pulling my hair out trying to understand how to do it. The best I could figure out was that I need to set this in the `config.xml` file of my module, but exactly what that command is/how it may be used, i haven't been able to figure out.

Can someone please guide me or show me how to accomplish this? If not, would it be too bad a practice to include a custom `config.php` file which connects to the database manually?

Comment: Click update, did you manage to get it to work? I would love to hear your solution as I'm kind of in the same situation you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you trying to use a resource model or entity ? here is how you can query a table using raw SQL but you need to know the tablename.

```
$w = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$result = $w->query('select entity_id from catalog_product_entity');

if (!$result) {
    return false;
}

$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!$row) {
    return false;
}
```

When trying to all a model you can use

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array(1,2)));

$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load();

foreach ($products as $_prod) {
   var_dump($_prod->getData());
}
```

I use the second method for my custom modules and it has worked out fine for me , hope this answer helps :)

Comment: Using that raw sql method  gives an error. I'm trying basically to connect to the db from a controller. Is that allowed?

Comment: I have not tried accessing the db directly from a controller. Can you try to create a Block that has a function with the raw sql method. 

You should be able to access that function from the indexAction() method of your controller.  

You might also want to look at the dispatch() , preDispatch() and postDispatch() methods of the controller. I'm unfortunately not familiar with them.

Comment: Rick, do you have any IM programs or MSN where I could chat to you for a bit? I have some questions which I haven't been able to find answers to, I'd really like some help with them

Comment: sorry man , i cant use any IM at work.... I can help on here , if only there was a pm feature!

Comment: In regards to the problem you're having with the raw SQL method... use getSingleton instead of getResourceSingleton.

Comment: hi Manos , what is the difference between Singleton and ResourceSingleton ... I would like to know. Thanks

Comment: @Rick - Not quite sure, I just found this after some debugging and testing. It was more hit and miss, than anything else...

Comment: @Manos - this answer should be edited, getResourceSingleton did not work for me but getSingleton, as you adviced, did.

Answer (score 0):

What about objects that do not have `addAttributeToFilter`? I've been trying for hours to load a role object by its name and nothing works. The only possible method is load, which would work perfectly if not for an unexplicable

```
if (!intval($value) && is_string($value)) {
   $field = 'role_id';
}
```

in `Mage_Admin_Model_Mysql4_Role::load`, which only makes it impossible to filter using a string value.

Magento has a `Rube Goldberg` architecture...